# How to provide additional argument in a public function for testing purposes?

Tags: python

I have a public function `fun(a, b)`. Now, for testing purposes, I would like that `fun` takes one additional argument `test_argument`.

What's the accepted way to do this?
My ideas:

```
def fun(a, b, test_argument=None):
    ...
```

but it's not pretty, because everyone using this function sees the `test_argument` argument, and it requires at least a comment.

```
def fun(a, b, **kwargs):
    ...
    test_argument = kwargs.get('test_argument', None)
```

now someone can wonder what is `**kwargs` for.

EDIT: I want this because `fun` is structured like follows:

```
def fun(a, b):
    do_locally(a, b)
    if condition(a, b):
        do_locally1(a, b)
        do_remotely_after_one_minute(a, b)
    else:
        do_locally2(a, b)
        do_remotely_after_two_minutes(a, b)
```

I would like to test the state of `a` and `b` after calling `fun(a, b)` but before the remote execution starts. However, in the project the code executed remotely is inlined in tests (0% chance to change this behaviour). So I thought about passing an additional argument:

```
def fun(a, b, test=False):
    do_locally(a, b)
    if condition(a, b):
        do_locally1(a, b)
        if not test:
            do_remotely_after_one_minute(a, b)
    else:
        do_locally2(a, b)
        if not test:
            do_remotely_after_two_minutes(a, b)
```

Comment: Given that you should really have docstrings explaining what your arguments are for anyway, what's the problem?

Comment: This sounds like a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me. **Why** do you think you need to pass in a test argument?

Comment: You should introduce an interface and pass different objects for the purpose of testing (a stub) or normal usage (it can be a default instance). Some kind of a policy pattern.

Comment: Write an interface function which takes 3 arguments and call within this function `fun(a,b)` while fun will refer to the 3rd variable defined in the outer function.

Comment: @kitek: Python's dynamic nature makes it possible to replace objects and functions temporarily during testing. You could use the [`mock` library](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/) to provide test mock-ups during a test.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I added the source of the problem.

Comment: @kitek: then mock `do_remotely_after_one_minute()` and `do_remotely_after_two_minutes()`. They are just global names looked up when `fun` runs.

Comment: @MartijnPieters In tests I'm importing `fun` from another module. How do I do it exactly then?

Comment: @kitek: you can replace those globals *on the module `fun` lives in*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both your `do_remotely_after_*` functions are just global names; they can be replaced temporarily during testing:

```
import module_under_test

def test_fun():
    # patch remote methods with noops
    draom = module_under_test.do_remotely_after_one_minute
    module_under_test.do_remotely_after_one_minute = lambda *args: pass
    dratm = module_under_test.do_remotely_after_two_minutes
    module_under_test.do_remotely_after_two_minutes = lambda *args: pass

    module_under_test.fun(a, b)

    # restore remote methods
    module_under_test.do_remotely_after_one_minute = draom
    module_under_test.do_remotely_after_two_minutes = dratw
```

You could use a context manager to handle the patching and restoring, but the best approach is to use the [`mock` library](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/) to handle that for you:

```
@mock.patch('module_under_test.do_remotely_after_one_minute')
@mock.patch('module_under_test.do_remotely_after_two_minutes')
def test_fun(mock_dratm, mock_draom):
    module_under_test.fun(a, b)
```

and have access to the mocks too, so you can assert if they have been called correctly.

Answer (score 1):

you should probably use `mock` library. It was made for exactly this staff:

```
>>> def do_loc(a,b):
...   return "IN do_loc %s %s" % (a, b)
... 
>>> def do_remte(a,b):
...   return "IN do_remte %s %s" % (a, b)
... 
>>> def foo(a,b):
...   print do_loc(a,b)
...   print do_remte(a,b)
... 
>>> with mock.patch('__main__.do_remte') as mock_remte:
...   mock_remte.return_value = "MY MOCK"
...   foo('A', 'B')
... 
IN do_loc A B
MY MOCK
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the nearly the same answer as Martijn Pieters', but using the `mock` library.

```
import module_under_test
try:
    # Standard library as of Python 3.4
    import unittest.mock as mock
except ImportError:
    # 3rd-party installation
    import mock

def test_fun():
    # patch remote methods with noops
    with mock.patch.multiple('module_under_test',
                             do_remotely_after_one_minute=mock.DEFAULT,
                             do_remotely_after_two_minute=mock.DEFAULT) as values:
        fun(a, b)
        # If desired, you can use values['do_remotely_after_one_minute'] to query
        # the mocked function as to whether or not it was called, what arguments
        # it was called with, etc.
```